# Is there a way to convert an excel file to a google sheet file with Google Apps scripts?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am working on trying to convert files that I am copying to a shared drive from my email.   The files are saved in xlsx and I lose information if I try to download them from the source as .csv files.

```
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet(fileName) {
  try {
    fileName = "JNJ Defects Last Shift.xlsx";

    var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    var fileId = excelFile.getId();
    var folderId = "0AEZiKNnbsme8Uk9PVA";
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
    //var resource = {
      //title: excelFile.getName(),
      //mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
      //parents: [{id: folderId}],
    //};
   
    blob.setContentType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet").setName("JNJ Defects Last Shift 22 Jun 20");
    DriveApp.createFile(blob);

    //Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

When I run it I get this error message

> [20-06-23 07:06:08:638 CDT] Exception: Invalid argument: file.contentType.

I have tried a couple of variations of the contentType but did not manage to convert to sheets.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can do this with the Advanced Drive Service.*

#### More Information:

In order to do the conversion, you need to specify specifically that you wish to convert the file, though as this will default to a Google Sheet format, you do not need to manually specify the MimeType.

#### Code:

```js
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet(fileName) {
    fileName = "JNJ Defects Last Shift.xlsx";

    var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    var fileId = excelFile.getId();
    var folderId = "0AEZiKNnbsme8Uk9PVA";
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
  
    var file = {
      title: "JNJ Defects Last Shift 22 Jun 20",
      parents: [
        {
          "kind": "drive#parentReference",
          "id": folderId
        }
      ]
    };
  
    file = Drive.Files.insert(file, blob, {
      convert: true      
    });  
}
```